# How to read JSON data on a webpage using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to read a json file `wifi_build_audit.json` from my webpage ,match the version (lets say `9.130.28.12.32.1.31`) and click on `submit` button in "Actions" column,I was able to get the point where I can open and login using password but need some help one how to read the json file and click on submit button?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://wifi-firmware-web.company.com:8080/wifi_build_audit")
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password)

driver.find_element_by_id("login-submit").click()
#Read json from wifi_build_audit.json
#Match the version `9.130.28.12.32.1.31` and click on "submit" in Actions column
```

Screenshot of my webpage

[image]

```
UPDATE:
Following are the steps am trying to automate

1.How to read json from wifi_build_audit.json file?
2.Match the version `9.130.28.12.32.1.31` in the JSON and click on "submit" in Actions column on the web page

wifi_build_audit.json
      [{
        "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1010c",
        "status": "Completed",
        "endRev": "c7a9aa810159699638d906f5de10195e990699973f1019",
        "chip": "9369",
        "startRev": "d009c101d7fb1016a66e89cd1019b010110110165ad3730e66f6",
        "audit": "Build Audit 9369/goatHW_9369 [9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.36] \n",
        "sanity": "none",
        "version": "9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.36",
        "branch": "goatHW_9369",
        "directory": "/SWE/Teams/tech/Furm/submissions/9369/9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.36",
        "requestTime": "10101018-03-1017T00:101101:1015.907Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "tag": "Official_9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.36",
        "swe": "baseline2101A10130",
        "projects": [
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_ekans",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1011015",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_sid",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1011019",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_maui",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1011013",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_kauai",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff101101101",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_midway",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff101101101",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_nihau",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1011010",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_lanai",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1010f",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_B101_hanauma",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1010e",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9369_Notes",
            "_id": "5aac5fb75071011018001015cff1010d",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          }
        ],
        "approvalNotes": [],
        "stepping": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "5aac638a60eb8c001015ff38cb",
        "status": "Queued",
        "endRev": "99d101c101d79ddbd10110169bc101cfb53f6339e1011019101d799f",
        "chip": "9355",
        "startRev": "6fad101101e9101d9ab81016ee67509101101101e9e9101e101931017f79",
        "audit": "Build Audit 9355/goatHW_9355 [9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.3101] \n",
        "sanity": "none",
        "version": "9.130.28.12.32.1.31",
        "branch": "goatHW_9355",
        "directory": "/SWE/Teams/tech/Furm/submissions/9355/9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.3101",
        "requestTime": "10101018-03-1017T00:38:39.1011019Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "tag": "Official_9.10130.1018.101101.3101.101.3101",
        "swe": "baseline101A10199",
        "projects": [
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9355_C101_hawaii",
            "_id": "5aac638a60eb8c001015ff38cd",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "BCMFurm_9355_Notes",
            "_id": "5aac638a60eb8c001015ff38cc",
            "submission": {
              "status": "passed",
              "system": "machine.company.com"
            }
          }
        ],
        "approvalNotes": [],
        "stepping": []
      }]
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Its not clear to me how to achieve this, am looking for some guidance, can you give some pointers?

Comment: Update the question with the expected text based formated `Json` and the steps further you are trying to _Automate_.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I updated the question, thing I can't figure out is `how do I read json (from wifi_build_audit.json file) from the webpage?`

Answer (score 1):

You can try open the url of `wifi_build_audit.json` in an new Tab, then read the content from browser, or using http client library to send a http request in your script and get the content from response.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("login-submit").click()

# open the json file in new tab
json_url = 'http://xxxxxx/wifi_build_audit.json'
driver.execute_script('window.open("'+json_url+'")')

# switch to the new tab
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# read the json content
json_content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > pre').text

# switch to the last window
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: can you please be specific with an example on what exactly you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to scrape the data from the webpage, as its available in the json file - selenium may not the right solution.

You just need to find the *link* for the submit button. You can do that by visiting the page in a browser, and right clicking on the link to view its source.

You need to find out what are the parameters passed to the server when that Submit is clicked.

Now your steps are:

1. Download the json file and read it.
2. Search for the desired version number
3. If found, send a request to the website (ie, click the Submit button)

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org); here is one way to do the above.

```
import requests

username = 'user'
password = 'sekret'

target_wifi_version = '1.2.3'

login_url = 'http://example.com/login'
json_url = 'http://example.com/sample.json'
submit_target = 'http://example.com/submit_results'

submit_form_params = {'wifi_id': ''}

with requests.Session() as s:
   s.post(login_url, data={'username': username, 'password': password})
   results = s.get(json_url).json()
   found = next((i for i in results if i['version'] == target_wifi_version), None)
   if found:
       submit_form_params['wifi_id'] = target_wifi_version
       s.post(submit_url, data=submit_form_params)
```